# Remove duplicate events within delta time

Tags: r

Given the datraframe below

```
  class           timestamp
1     A 2019-02-14 15:00:29
2     A 2019-01-27 17:59:53
3     A 2019-01-27 18:00:00
4     B 2019-02-02 18:00:00
5     C 2019-03-08 16:00:37
```

observation 2 and 3 point to the same event. How do I remove rows belonging to the same class if another timestamp within 2 minutes already exists?

Desired output:

```
  class           timestamp
1     A 2019-02-14 15:00:00
2     B 2019-01-27 18:00:00
3     A 2019-02-02 18:00:00
4     C 2019-03-08 16:00:00
```

`round( ,c("mins"))` can be used to get rid of the second component but if the timestamps are to far off some test samples will be rounded to the wrong minute leaving still different timestamps

Comment: @RonakShah this would be preferable at the end, maybe using round, but not stricly necessary. The first problem is to get rid of all entries which are within 2 minutes of one another. If leaving the XX:00:00 constraint out makes the solution much easier it's appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I think I over-complicated the problem in first attempt, I think what would work for your case is to round time for 2 minute intervals which we can do using `round_date` from `lubridate` .

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = round_date(as.POSIXct(timestamp), unit = "2 minutes")) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(timestamp))

# class timestamp          
#  <chr> <dttm>             
#1 A     2019-02-14 15:00:00
#2 A     2019-01-27 18:00:00
#3 B     2019-02-02 18:00:00
#4 C     2019-03-08 16:00:00
```

---

**Original Attempt**

We can first convert the `timestamp` to `POSIXct` object, then `arrange` rows by `class` and `timestamp`, use `cut` to divide them into `"2 min"` interval and then remove duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp)) %>%
 arrange(class, timestamp) %>%
 group_by(class) %>%
 filter(!duplicated(as.numeric(cut(timestamp, breaks = "2 mins")), fromLast = TRUE))


# class timestamp          
#  <chr> <dttm>             
#1 A     2019-01-27 18:00:00
#2 A     2019-02-14 15:00:29
#3 B     2019-02-02 18:00:00
#4 C     2019-03-08 16:00:37
```

Here, I haven't changed or rounded the `timestamp` column and kept it as it is but it would be simple to `round` it if you use `cut` in `mutate`. Also  if you want to keep the first entry like `2019-01-27 17:59:53` then remove `fromLast = TRUE` argument.

Comment: Sorry I have to get back to you: when attempting to run the above command with `df <- data.frame(class = c('A','A','A'), timestamp = c('2019-03-15 15:30:00','2019-04-13 16:59:56','2019-04-13 17:00:00'))
` the entries do not get filtered correctly.

Comment: @user3394605 Sorry, I misunderstood your problem at first. Can you check the updated answer?